# SSL alternative names mismatch

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, sni, subject-alternative-names

Santander want to use our website, however when trying to access it they receive the following error:

'Network Error: Your request contacted a host which presented a certificate signed by an untrusted issuer.'

This appears on a page in red text and their logo, so it's a custom message they're throwing when verifying our site is safe to use. Their technical team have responded to say that it's due to an expired cert on our site, being **DST Root CA X3** which I believe is a legacy certificate used by LetsEncrypt (who we use for our certs). This is the Certification Paths output from ssllabs.com for our site's cert:

[image: ssllabs certification paths for site cert]

From what I've read, I believe this shouldn't cause a problem unless they're using extremely old web browsers, because any modern browser should use 'Path #1'?

Separately they've also said that there's an 'alternative names' mismatch issue too, which when put through ssllabs shows the following. It is listed as 'Certificate #2' and belongs to Fastly, so it makes sense that their alternative names won't include our domain.

[image: ssllabs certificate 2]

My understanding for this is that it shouldn't cause a problem unless they are somehow trying to get to our site without SNI enabled?

These exact two issues can also be found by analyzing the Stanford university website: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.stanford.edu&s=151.101.2.133&latest

My primary questions are:

1. Could any of these two 'issues' be causing their problem? And if so, what are my possible solutions?
2. What questions should I be asking them to further understand the problem they're having?
3. Where does ssllabs get the 2nd certificate from?

My SSL knowledge is limited, so please be kind.

Answer (score 2):

The second certificate comes from trying to connect the host without the Server Name Indication (SNI; [RFC 6606, 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-3)). As SNI is a [20 year old](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3546#section-3.1) technology, it is widely supported by everyone and likely not causing the problem. Also, the `www` subdomain of your domain using the certificate from the first picture is served from 4xIPv4 & 4xIPv6 addresses, all currently giving a valid certificate for the hostname.

The question you should be asking is whether they have the `ISRG Root X1` in their trusted CA store.